# SQL Find specific date where rooms are not fully taken

Tags: java, sql, datetime, sum, subquery

I have two tables:

One that has a table like this:
Table Name Reservations:

```
Name Room Seats Date
John 101  20    11/22
```

---

Table Name Rooms:

```
Name Seats
101  30
202  40

SELECT *
FROM Reservations
WHERE date = '2020-11-22' AND
SELECT Reservations.Room
FROM Reservations
WHERE Reservations.Room NOT IN(SELECT Room.Name FROM Room)
```

I tried the statement above, but it is not working. I want the command to return all the rooms in a date that are not used. It should return Room 202. That is it.

Comment: Please provide sample data and a clear explanation of the logic you want to implement.

Comment: I already did. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want rooms that have seats left for the given date. One option uses a subquery for filtering:

```
select ro.*
from rooms ro
where ro.seats > (
    select coalesce(sum(re.seats), 0)
    from reservations re
    where re.room = ro.name and re.date = '2020-11-12'
)
```

On the other hand, if you want rooms for which no reservation at all exists for the given date, then use `not exists`:

```
select ro.*
from rooms ro
where not exists (
    select 1
    from reservations re
    where re.room = ro.name and re.date = '2020-11-12'
)
```

Comment: I am not sure why are also adding seat number. This is not needed .:D

Comment: Well I supposed that there might be several reservations for the same room and date. But it doesn't hurt if that's not the case, the query still works as itended.

Comment: This statement is not working. Can you please modify with what I need. I tried to modify it and it wont work.

Comment: @Jabbaa11: why don't you want room 101 in the result? It is not *fully taken* (there are 30 seats, and only 20 are taken).

Comment: I know this program sounds weird but all I need is for the statement to return the rooms that have not been taken on a certain date.

Comment: I am so sorry. THis worked perfect. I mis-wrote a piece. Thank you so much.